# MODx MIGX variable in json string

Tags: json, modx

I have a little problem with using a variable inside the where-json-string.
I'm running a MIGX getImageList inside an other MIGX getImageList -template.

```
[[getImageList? 
&tvname=`migxProducts` 
&where=`{"productGroupName:=":"[[+productGroupName]]","productItemType:=":"product"}` 
&tpl=`migxProductsListRowTpl`]]
```

It seems that it's the [[+productGroupName]] that breaks it all. I need to use that variable in the where string.

Any clue of what's wrong or if there's a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How are you grabbing your `productGroupName` variable ?
I think you might be mixing `MODX` tags.

If it's a TV set on the current resource, you might want to use `[[*productGroupName]]`.

If it's pulled from a `getResources` call, you might want to either make sure the prefix is empty (with the parameter `getResources?… &tvPrefix=`) or use the default prefix: `[[+tv.productGroupName]]`.

I hope that will help.

Comment: I don't think that's it. The variable is working just fine a couple of rows earlier. It's when it's run inside the json string that it breaks the code. I'm using MIGX: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/MIGX